# Some questions about Flask authentication

Tags: python, flask

I have read some posts about Http Basic authentication. For example, http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask. I come up questions.

1. If app.route('/secret_main') is login required, then how to include app.route('/secret_main/subs') to be protected?
2. Because Http basic can't be expired, so how to clean up it from Flask?
3. If Http basic has problem, what is the best popular way to secure your RESTful API?

Comment: your 3rd question is definitely off-topic for So because it's opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can either wrap the second route with `@auth.login_required`, or you can add both to a [Blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#blueprint-objects) like so:

```py
    mod = Blueprint('secret_main', __name__, prefix='/secret_main')
    mod.before_request(auth.login_required)

    @mod.route('/')
    def secret_main():
        return 'This content is protected.'

    @mod.route('/subs')
    def secret_sub():
        return 'This content is also protected.'

    app.register_blueprint(mod)
```

2. Session expiration isn't really something you can do with HTTP Basic auth. Expiration means you'd want a user to re-authenticate after a certain amount of time. With HTTP Basic, the client sends the actual login credentials with each request. So the user is already renewing their session on *every request*.
3. Used properly, you can rely on HTTP basic to work correctly. However, it has its [weaknesses](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Weak_Authentication_Methods). The main problem is that the credentials are sent unencrypted with each request. So on unencrypted, non-HTTPS connections, an attacker could intercept someone's login credentials.

Comment: I am new for Flask. Thanks your answer so I can use Blueprint to do all sub directory protection.